# Large size file upload related to custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, governorlimits, limits

Is it possible to upload the files with size more than 25MB and can we show them in related list of a custom object? what is the best way to achieve this?
Do we need to use external storage if the size limit crosses 2GB limit?
can we upload the files via VF page?

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can do this using chatter. Check here [Upload a File as Large as 2GB in Salesforce Using a Visualforce Page](http://appirio.com/category/tech-blog/2015/11/upload-a-file-as-large-as-2gb-in-salesforce-using-a-visualforce-page/)

Basically what you need to do here is include chatter component in the VF page and then using some CSS display it and attach file of 2 GB.

```
<chatter:feed entityId="<ID of the custom object record>" />
```

Now some CSS and javascript

```
$('.uploadFileSizeLimit').hide();           

$('.contentPublisherSlideDown.customPanel.alignTop').css('border', '0');

$('.clearContentPanelButtonContainer').hide();

$('.publisherFeedItemTypeChoices').hide();      

$('.cxfeedinnerwrapper').hide();  

$('.publisherBottomBarPlaceholder').hide();

$('.publisherTextAreaPlaceholder.alignCenter').hide();
```

And

```
if($('.file')[1].files.length > 0){

                   $('#publishersharebutton').trigger('click');

}else{

                   alert('Please select a file');

}
```

Your icon look like
[image]

But if you want to upload more then 2 GB in single shot then you need external server(Drive, Dropbox) for this.

Comment: Clever way of using VF and Chatter. I'd imagine it'd also be possible to use REST or SOAP in Visualforce as well?

Comment: @DanJones - REST - may be, but definitely NOT with SOAP. There is something called SOAP streaming of large files, but NOT many SOAP servers supports that functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a [resource](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=content_file_size_limits.htm&language=en).

> The following are maximum file size limits for files in Salesforce CRM Content:
>
> - 2 GB
> - 2 GB (including headers) when uploaded via Chatter REST API
> - 2 GB (including headers) when uploaded via REST API
> - 38 MB when uploaded via SOAP API
> - 10 MB for Google Docs
> - 10 MB when uploaded via Visualforce

So to answer your questions:

> Is it possible to upload the files with size more than 25MB and can we show them in related list of a custom object?

Yes.

> what is the best way to achieve this?

As Tushar said, Chatter would be one way, otherwise you'd want to look at using the REST API for large file sizes.

> Do we need to use external storage if the size limit crosses 2GB limit?

Yes. You'd probably want to look at other solutions (SharePoint, OneDrive, Google Drive, Dropbox etc...).

> can we upload the files via VF page?

Yes, but only to a 10Mb limit.

Or you can do as Tushar says by uploading directly to the Attachment object:

> create new attachment and directly upload in attachment. It will allow you to save 25 MB file.

Comment: Update from VF page you can upload file of 25 MB.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you have a resource? I could only find what I'd originally linked and [this](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_size_limits.htm&language=en_US)?

Comment: create new attachment and directly upload in attachment. It will allow you to save 25 MB file. :)

Comment: @TusharSharma Actually, there's a memory limit (heap), so no, you can't upload a 25MB file in Visualforce. You need to use the API for files above the heap limit.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have tested this many time and still using. Just create new attachment instance and save the record and use `pagerefernce` type method and return to another page or reload same page. You can easily save the record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Salesforce Content object to store large file size and use it as related list